# How to implement nested XML structure into 2 ListViews?

Tags: android, xml, listview, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to parse an XML file with the following structure:

```
<groups>
  <group>
    <id>...</id>
    <name>...</name>
    <description>...</description>
    <actions>
      <action>...</action>
      <action>...</action>
    </actions>
  </group>
  <group>
    <id>...</id>
    <name>...</name>
    <description>...</description>
    <actions>
      <action>...</action>
      <action>...</action>
      <action>...</action>
    </actions>
  </group>
  <group>
    <id>...</id>
    <name>...</name>
    <description>...</description>
    <actions>
      <action>...</action>
    </actions>
  </group>
</groups>
```

Currently in the first ListView I have "name" and "description" visible per row. This is fully functional. When selecting a row a new activity is created with another ListView. It is here where I want to display an action per row based on the selected position in the previous list. How should I do this? I have tried to also add the "action"s to the map where my other items are added to but it only adds 1 "action" per group.
Please advise?

public class ErrorCodeList extends ListActivity {

```
public static final String LANGUAGE = null;

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist;
public ListAdapter adapter;
public Dialog progDialog;
public ProgressBar progBar;
public TextView lblMessage;

private Intent myIntent;
private String  URLvariable;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);

    myIntent = getIntent();
    URLvariable = myIntent.getExtras().getString("urlType");

    mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.activity_error_list, 
                    new String[] { "tid", "tname" }, 
                    new int[] { R.id.item_id, R.id.item_title });

    final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                 

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),ErrorCodeDetails.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("map",hashMap);
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });

    progDialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.progress_dialog);
    progDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_dialog);

    progBar = (ProgressBar) progDialog.findViewById(R.id.progBar);
    lblMessage = (TextView) progDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtProgMessage);
    lblMessage.setText("Please Wait.....");

    progDialog.show();
    new GetDataTask().execute();        

}


private Boolean isOnline()  {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(ni != null && ni.isConnected())
        return true;

    return false;
}

private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

        if(isOnline()){
            mylist.clear();                  
            }  

            // Start the http request
            String feedURL="http://...";        
            String xml = XMLfunctions.getXML(feedURL);
            Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(xml);

            int numResults = 1;

            if((numResults <= 0)){
                Toast.makeText(ErrorCodeList.this, "Geen resultaten gevonden", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                finish();
            }

            NodeList troubles = doc.getElementsByTagName("trouble");

            for (int i = 0; i < troubles.getLength(); i++) {                            
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    

                Element e = (Element)troubles.item(i);
                if((e.getAttributes().getNamedItem("type").getNodeValue().equals("error"))) {
                    //map.put("id", "ID:" + Integer.valueOf(e.getAttributes().getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue()));
                    //map.put("status", "Status:" + (e.getAttributes().getNamedItem("status").getNodeValue()));
                    map.put("tid", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "id"));
                    map.put("tname", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "name"));
                    map.put("tdescription", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "description"));

                    //NodeList  ns=e.getElementsByTagName("trouble_cause");
                    mylist.add(map);
                }           
            }
            System.out.println(mylist);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(ErrorCodeList.this, "No connection..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
        }

        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {

        setListAdapter(adapter);
        progDialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Take a look on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: I am not looking for an expendable list because Some other content has to be added at the list of actions. Therefore I'm looking for a new screen (activity) where a new ListView is shown. My problem is that I do not know the correct way to add the actions to my arrayList. The other items were added via a hashmap<string,string> but I am getting a problem when pointing to multiple action.

Comment: You mentioned using an array list which seems like the way to go to me. What exactly was the problem?

Comment: Correct. The problem is I that now I have a hashmap<string,string> that is being added to my mylist arrayList. In this hashmap "id","name" and "description" are added and passed correctly to the ListView. But the actions I have a difficulty with. It seems I cannot add an hashmap into a hashmap. My feeling is that this approach is incorrect.

Comment: To add to this currently I use a simpleAdapter to pass the mylist arrayList to the listview.

Comment: You can add a hashmap into a hashmap if the type is something like HashMap< String , HashMap<String , String>>. Why don't you add the actions (the values) into an arraylist and use that as the basis of a listview? Don't suppose you can post code so we can make more precise suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a data object Group.

```
public class Group {
private String id;
private String name;
private String description;
private ArrayList<String> actions;
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
public ArrayList<String> getActions() {
    return actions;
}
public void setActions(ArrayList<String> actions) {
    this.actions = actions;
}
}
```

Your activity code will look something like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

private ArrayList<Group> groups;
private ListView list;
private MyAdapter adapter;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.my_list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter = new MyAdapter());
    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    parseXML();
}


private void parseXML(){
    // TODO: CODE TO PARSE XML
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}


public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groups.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groups.get(0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO: Create row view here.
        // USE groups to create list here
        return null;
    }

}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View rowView, int position, long column) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Group clickedGroup = groups.get(position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putStringArrayList("ACTIONS", clickedGroup.getActions());
    intent.putExtra("BUNDLE", bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

Your second activity will look something like this

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

private ArrayList<String> actions;
private ListView list;
private ActionAdapter adapter;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");
    actions = bundle.getStringArrayList("ACTIONS");

    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.my_list2);
    list.setAdapter(adapter = new ActionAdapter());
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}


public class ActionAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return actions.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return actions.get(0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO: Create row view here.
        // USE actions to create list here
        return null;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Wooow!! Nice explanation! How should the XML parsing happen with the group data object? Can I throw away my way of parsing the XML? Or should I insert that script into the XMLparser() function. Thanks for your time so far!!

Comment: Parsing XML file will be somewhat similar to your method, but instead of adding name-value pair in hashmap, create an object of 'Group' and set the properties. Add this object in ArrayList 'groups' and you should be good to go. I can see you are using async task to perform parsing, which is good. Try it out.. You will be able to resolve it.