# How to achieve the following structure for my Android App?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I am looking to achieve the following structure:

- `ArrayList`

  - `HashMap`

    - `ArrayList`

      - `HashMap`
      - `HashMap`
  - `HashMap`

    - `ArrayList`

      - `HashMap`
      - `HashMap`
      - `HashMap`

How do I add an `ArrayList` to a `HashMap`?

Answer (score 1):

What for this structure is used? Simplify it.

The best place to store it is bunch of tables in sqlite db.

Comment: I parsed an external XML file which fills a ListView when selecting a row in the ListView another activity is opened with a listview containing the deepest arrayList filled with hashmaps.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, MyObject>>>> wierdDataStructure;
```

Comment: Its a list of hashmaps where each hashmaps ha a string key and a list object as value. This internal list is nothing but again list of hashmaps where each hashmaps has a string key and 'MyObject' value.

Comment: But what if I also would like to add an object in the first level Hashmap?

Comment: Please find this question for the full explanation of what I am trying to achieve but nobody seems to be able/wanting to help me. [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966877/how-to-implement-nested-xml-structure-into-2-listviews)

Comment: Looked at your original question. Looks to me like you require complete restructuring of classes. I have posted an alternate method, please try it and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify this huge structure, you can create a custom class:

```
public class WeirdObject<D> extends ArrayList<HashMap<String, D>> {
    // Your custom methods here for easy construction and interaction with this class
}
```

And to add objects:

```
WeirdObject<WeirdObject<Double>> weirdObject = new WeirdObject<WeirdObject<Double>>();
HashMap<String, WeirdObject<MyObject>> hashMap = new HashMap<String, WeirdObject<MyObject>>();
// add your WeirdObjects (AKA ArrayList<Hashmap<String, MyObject>)
weirdObject.add(hashMap);
```